# How to make font size adapt to character length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make font size on paragraph automatically adapt to space of div depend on the length of character?

Example 1

```
p{
 font-size:15px;
}

<div class="caption">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, quis.</p>
</div>
```

Because the character length of that paragraph is long the font size will be just `10px`.

If like this

```
<div class="caption">
<p>Lorem</p>
</div>
```

The font size will be `20px` because the character length of that paragraph is short.

Comment: You can't do that with CSS...you need Javascript

Comment: how sir, can u help me

Comment: https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js/blob/master/README.md

Comment: pardon me if i wrong. does fitTex for responsive media? like when i use mobile then the font size will get resize?

Answer (score 0):

CSS vw and vh units allow to resize depending on the view width and view height of the browser. Here is a nice article about view height and view width units : https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Try using this for example:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

Also I am unsure if this works for scaling text inside a div. The solution above works concerning the viewport which is the size of the window of the browser. If you want it to work for a div I would suggest using javascript since I doubt css works on it's own.
You can use this for the text to scale : [TextFit](https://github.com/nbrunt/TextFit)

### To summerize

If you want the text size to depend on the browser window width use the first given solution. Using vh and wh units in CSS.

If you want to resize font size depending on a container width, use javascript with calculation or use the given tool : TextFit

Comment: not working sir with textFit. when i just have 2 character inside the div. the font-size didnt get bigger.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, I'm sorry, you maybe want to count the number of words and select a size for each interval you desire. Consider reading this https://css-tricks.com/set-font-size-based-on-word-count/

Comment: Thank you btw, i just want to transform font-size by how much character that one div can have. example: if Lorem ipsum, transform font-size:15px;
and if Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,transform font-size:5px;  @kunamatata